# How To Take A BufferedImage From JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, jeditorpane

I need to load a URL into a JEditorPane, then take a BufferedImge from the JEditorPane, my code below will get me a blank/black image :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Html_Browser
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Dimension screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    JEditorPane editorPane=new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
    editorPane.setEditable(false);

    try
    {
      editorPane.setPage("https://news.yahoo.com/");
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      BufferedImage saveimg=new BufferedImage((int)screenSize.getWidth(),(int)screenSize.getHeight()-36,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      Graphics2D g2=saveimg.createGraphics();
      editorPane.paint(g2); 
      ImageIO.write(saveimg,"png",new File("test.png"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
      editorPane.setText("<html>Connection issues!</html>");
    }
    
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(editorPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(0,0,(int)screenSize.getWidth(),(int)screenSize.getHeight()-36);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I added a 3-second delay, but it didn't work, what's the right way to do it ?

Comment: You need to 1) load the Swing application on the event thread and 2) get rid of the Thread.sleep since that blocks Swing GUI updates and drawings and gives you no advantage at all. If you need a delay, use a Swing Timer, or perhaps load the web page using a SwingWorker and gather the image in the `done()` call-back method when the worker has completed its work.

Comment: You also need to render the component before it can create an image. This means it should display first, and then draw the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use this approach.

It modifies the editor pane to read all the files synchronously. Then a `PropertyChanngeEvent` is generated when the I/O is finished.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class EditorPaneLoadSynchronously extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener
{
    private JEditorPane html;
    private JTextField webURL;

    public EditorPaneLoadSynchronously()
    {
        JPanel urlPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(urlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        webURL = new JTextField("https://stackoverflow.com", 15);
        webURL.addActionListener(this);
        urlPanel.add(webURL);

        JButton gotoURL = new JButton("Goto URL");
        gotoURL.addActionListener(this);
        urlPanel.add(gotoURL);

        HTMLEditorKit editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit()
        {
            private final ViewFactory factory = new HTMLFactory()
            {
                public View create(Element elem)
                {
                    View v = super.create(elem);

                    if ((v != null) && (v instanceof ImageView))
                    {
                        ((ImageView)v).setLoadsSynchronously( true );
                    }

                    return v;
                }
            };

            public ViewFactory getViewFactory()
            {
                return factory;
            }
        };

        html = new JEditorPane();
//      html.setEditorKit( editorKit );
//      html.setEditable( false );
        html.addPropertyChangeListener("page", this);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(html);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 400) );
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
//          html.setDocument( new HTMLDocument() );
            html.setPage( new URL(webURL.getText()) );
            System.out.println("After setPage");
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Page Loaded");
//          BufferedImage bi = ScreenImage.createImage(html);
//          ScreenImage.writeImage(bi, "sync.jpg");
        }
        catch(Exception ee) {}
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        EditorPaneLoadSynchronously frame = new EditorPaneLoadSynchronously();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        frame.actionPerformed(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Note: the above code uses the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) convenience class. You can replace it with your only code to create and write the BufferedImage.

Comment: Great, it's more than what I asked for, thanks. But I've noticed something, when the apps runs, I got some error message : After setPage
[ERROR   ] EXCEPTION
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: ", "
 at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194)
 at com.inet.html.utils.URLUtils.decode(URLUtils.java:81)
...java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Page Loaded

Comment: @Frank, not sure what the issue is. However, you need to remember that JEditorPane will only display a subset of HTML3.2 and will not display any current webpage accurately.

Comment: Yes, I'm upset that latest Java can't display/parse up-to-date html properly. But I'm glad to see your solution, it works great, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to draw a component before you've rendered the GUI, including the component, and this won't work. Suggestions include:

- Load the GUI on the Swing event thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`
- Load any web data in a background thread, using a SwingWorker. Or else get the web page in the main thread before creating the Swing GUI and then pass it into the Swing GUI.
- Only create your image after the web page has loaded and the GUI has rendered (made visible)
- Get rid of all `Thread.sleep` calls. These aren't your friend and will only serve to hobble the Swing GUI rendering.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EditorStuff extends JPanel {
    private static final String URL_PATH = "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html";
    private JEditorPane editorPane;

    public EditorStuff(URL url) throws IOException {
        int w = 800;
        int h = 650;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        editorPane = new JEditorPane(url);
        // editorPane.setPage(url);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void captureImage() throws IOException {
        int w = editorPane.getWidth();
        int h = editorPane.getHeight();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        editorPane.paint(g2);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("test.png"));
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_PATH);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(url));
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(final URL url) {
        try {
            EditorStuff mainPanel = new EditorStuff(url);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("EditorStuff");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            mainPanel.captureImage();  // called *after* rendering
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Any sample code ?* - lots. search the site. You should find examples of a SwingWorker or a link to the Swing tutorial on using the SwingWorker.

Comment: Doesn't work for "stackoverflow.com". All the I/O is NOT done on the EDT even though the I/O is initiated on the EDT. I believe that the original HTML file may be initially read before the `setPage(...)` method returns, However, there are still many more reads necessary to read the images and files from any other links specified in the MTHL. You don't know when the I/O for all files is completed and when the rendering is completed. The best option is to have the user click a button when the HTML is rendered.